# Manipulating body of a mass email

Tags: apex, massemailmessage

I am using MassEmailMessage in APEX and I am trying to manipulate the body of the mass email message. I have successfully done this in a SingleEmailMessage. Here is my code:

```
EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id =: '00Xm0000000QEX5'];
String subject = 'Hello';
String htmlBody = emailTemplate.HtmlValue;
htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!PNAME}, c.FirstName);

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

mail.setReplyTo(fromaddress);
mail.setSenderDisplayName(fromaddress);
mail.setTargetObjectId(objId);
mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
mail.setSubject(subject);
mail.setHtmlBody(htmlBody);
```

So when using MassEmailMessage, I don't have these methods at my disposal, so I am wondering if I can do something similar somehow.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass mail requires an EmailTemplate. Indentical to the way the UI works, your only option is to send the email verbatim without modification. To be able to specify a body, you can only use the single email format.

Comment: I will need to send up to 750 emails sometimes - any ideas how I can achieve this with SingleEmailMessage? Tia.

Comment: You'll probably need to use a batch class to properly send out that quantity of emails. You can trigger the batch class from another source, like a Visualforce page, executeAnonymous call, or a trigger.

Comment: I now split up my emails into batches of 10 and send them out as single email messages. this works fine now. tks